# How to install sigsegv glibc module

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, fedora, ld-preload, gnulib

I am trying to trap a segmentation fault and the old LD_PRELOAD approach has been deprecated in 2022 (https://www.marcusfolkesson.se/blog/libsegfault/)

I was reading about this new contribution *sigsegv* and would like to use it. However I am unable to install the library.
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2021-05/msg00072.html

I am running Fedora and tried `sudo dnf install -y libsigsegv-dev` to no avail (thanks for nothing ChatGPT :)

Where can I find this library and how do you install it on Fedora?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed two options for easily catching SIGSEGV on Unix platforms:

- Use of the Gnulib module `sigsegv`. The [Gnulib documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/) describes how to integrate it into the build system of your package.
- Use of libsigsegv as a pre-installed library.

In both cases, `#include <sigsegv.h>` in your package, and use the function `sigsegv_install_handler` and/or `stackoverflow_install_handler`.

Comment: Hi Bruno. Thank you for taking the time to help me.  I did look in that documentation that you referenced. Then (and just now when I looked again) I found no reference for sigsegv except in the discussion about signal.h. Am I missing something?
Also - what is the way to install it on Fedora (which was the question)?

Comment: Not every Gnulib module has HTML-formatted documentation. For the sigsegv module, you need to look in the sigsegv.in.h file, to understand how to use the module.

Comment: Thanks @bruno. Now I know where to look. So your answer is partially correct as it is not documented anywhere I can find (not even in the PDF version). But I have enough to start experimenting. Thanks again